# Tasklist doesn't have access to a certain process

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, exe, tasklist

I made a batch file with the following script:

```
@echo off
goto start

:start
"C:\Games\SV_Debug\Data\Win32\InvisibleM2.vbs"
goto check

:check
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Launcher2.exe" >swap | find /I /N "Launcher2.exe" >swap
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" (
    goto waitrecheck
) else "%ERRORLEVEL%" (
    goto start
)

:waitrecheck
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3
goto check
```

This batch file is executed by a vbscript that make's this batch invisible.
The batch file runs a vbscript that runs Launcher2.exe normal and not invisible.

But this batch above here can't check is Launcher2.exe is running.
When it tries I get this error:

> The process does not have access to the file because it's being used by another program.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you need separate VBS and batch files anyway? VBS can do all of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Launcher2.exe" >swap | find /I /N "Launcher2.exe" >swap
```

You can not send the output of two programs to the same file at the same time

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Launcher2.exe" | find /I /N "Launcher2.exe" >nul
```